# SwiftUI List redraw the content of a presented sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm having an issue with SwiftUI with a presented `.sheet` when a `List` content change. Let me explain in detail the situation.

I provided [a sample example on Github](https://github.com/bpisano/ListSheetIssue) that you can clone so you can easily reproduce the bug.

### Context

---

I have only 2 views :

- `PlaylistCreationView`
- `SearchView`

Each of them have respectively their view models called `PlaylistCreationViewModel` and `SearchViewModel`.

The `PlaylistCreationView` has a `Add Songs` button witch will present the `SearchView` has a `sheet`. When the user touch a song in the search results, the `SearchView` sends a `onAddSong` completion handler that will notify the `PlaylistCreationView` that a song has been added.

Here a simple schema of the situation:

[image: Situation]

Here is also some screenshots of the views:

#### PlaylistCreationView

[image: PlaylistCreationView]

#### SearchView

[image: SearchView]

### Problem

When the user touch a song in the `SearchView`, the `SearchView` content is redrawn. I mean the view is recreated. The view appears has if it have been loaded for the first time again. Just like this:

[image: Blank Search]

To simplify the problem, here is another schema of the situation:

[image: Problem Schema]

Here is what I can observe just after touching a song:

[image]

As you can see, the song has been added to the playlist correctly, but the `SearchView` is now blank because it has been recreated.

What I can't explain, is why the change of a list in the `PlaylistCreationViewModel` leads to redrawing the presented `sheet`.

### How to reproduce the issue

---

I provided [a sample example on Github](https://github.com/bpisano/ListSheetIssue) that you can clone. To reproduce the issue:

1. Clone the project and run it on any iPhone simulator.
2. Touch "Add song".
3. Type something on the search bar at the top of the search view.
4. Select a song. Your search should have disappeared because the view has been rebuilded.

### Code

---

#### PlaylistCreationViewModel

```swift
final class PlaylistCreationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sheetType: SheetType?
    @Published var songs: [String] = []
    
}

extension PlaylistCreationViewModel {
    
    enum SheetType: String, Identifiable {
        
        case search
        
        var id: String {
            rawValue
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

#### PlaylistCreationView

```swift
struct PlaylistCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlaylistCreationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.songs, id: \.self) { song in
                    Text(song)
                }
                Button("Add Song") {
                    viewModel.sheetType = .search
                }
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Playlist")
        }
        .sheet(item: $viewModel.sheetType) { _ in
            sheetView
        }
    }
    
    private var sheetView: some View {
        let addingMode: SearchViewModel.AddingMode = .playlist { addedSong in
            // This line leads SwiftUI to rebuild the SearchView
            viewModel.songs.append(addedSong)
        }
        let sheetViewModel: SearchViewModel = SearchViewModel(addingMode: addingMode)
        return NavigationView {
            SearchView(viewModel: sheetViewModel)
                .navigationTitle("Search")
        }
    }
    
}
```

#### SearchViewModel

```swift
final class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var search: String = ""
    let songs: [String] = ["Within", "One more time", "Veridis quo"]
    let addingMode: AddingMode
    
    init(addingMode: AddingMode) {
        self.addingMode = addingMode
    }
    
}

extension SearchViewModel {
    
    enum AddingMode {
        
        case playlist(onAddSong: (_ song: String) -> Void)
        
    }
    
}
```

#### SearchView

```swift
struct SearchView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SearchViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $viewModel.search)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            List(viewModel.songs, id: \.self) { song in
                Button(song) {
                    switch viewModel.addingMode {
                    case .playlist(onAddSong: let onAddSong):
                        onAddSong(song)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm pretty sure it is some SwiftUI stuff that I'm missing. But I can't get it. I didn't encountered such a case before. I couldn't find anything on the web.

Any help or advice would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance to anyone who'll take the time to read and understand the problem. I hope I've described the problem well enough.

Comment: Do you have to use 100% sheet? I mean why not a CustomView then all problems solved, because sheet is kind of buggy, even if some one find the issue in your code, it would be kind of understanding bug and dealing with that, and maybe that salvation would not necessary with new update of Xcode or SwiftUI. I am 99% sure this issue is not about your code, but it is about sheet.

Comment: @swiftPunk thanks for your reply. I don't have to use a sheet. But this is a standard way to navigate across iOS apps and would be appreciable for the user experience. If this is a bug, I'll report it to Apple. But I want to be sure that this is not an error from myself.

Comment: What is a sheet? sheet is nothing more than an animation of showing a View, you can do that with some coding, if do not want code, then you need to deal with apple bugy sheets. I have lots of experience with sheet, they just do not ready full use,

Comment: @swiftPunk the main advantage to me of using sheet is because of the multiplatform app I'm building. It would have been great to take advantage of the simplicity of the component. For now I'll have to find another solution and report the bug to Apple. Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

When you tap on Songs in `SearchView` you are invoking a `closure` block, that is defined inside `Sheet` view. The code below-:

```
private var sheetView: some View {
    let addingMode: SearchViewModel.AddingMode = .playlist { addedSong in
        // This line leads SwiftUI to rebuild the SearchView
        viewModel.songs.append(addedSong)
    }
    let sheetViewModel: SearchViewModel = SearchViewModel(addingMode: addingMode)
    return NavigationView {
        SearchView(viewModel: sheetViewModel)
            .navigationTitle("Search")
    }
}
```

The goal of this closure is to add selected song in `Songs` array, present in `PlaylistCreationViewModel`  class. Below is that class-:

```
final class PlaylistCreationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sheetType: SheetType?
    @Published var songs: [String] = []
    
}
```

As you can see this class is `ObservableObject` , and your `songs` array is `@Published` property, as soon as you add a song to this array, any class that is using this model and marked with `@ObservedObject` will refresh its **body** .In your case that class is below-:

```
struct PlaylistCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlaylistCreationViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.songs, id: \.self) { song in
                    Text(song)
                }
                Button("Add Song") {
                    viewModel.sheetType = .search
                }
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Playlist")
        }
        .sheet(item: $viewModel.sheetType) { _ in
            sheetView
        }
    }
    
    private var sheetView: some View {
        let addingMode: SearchViewModel.AddingMode = .playlist { addedSong in
            // This line leads SwiftUI to rebuild the SearchView
            viewModel.songs.append(addedSong)
        }
        let sheetViewModel: SearchViewModel = SearchViewModel(addingMode: addingMode)
        return NavigationView {
            SearchView(viewModel: sheetViewModel)
                .navigationTitle("Search")
        }
    }
```

Now when this view gets refreshed after adding a **song** it will also reload `sheetView` view, why? because your sheet is reading its state from `viewModel.sheetType`  whose values is still set to `.search`

Now, when sheet is called, it also create `SearchViewModel` objects again, and give it to `SearchView`, So you are getting complete **new Object** with empty search string. Below is that model class-:

```
final class SearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var search: String = ""
    let songs: [String] = ["Within", "One more time", "Veridis quo"]
    let addingMode: AddingMode
    
    init(addingMode: AddingMode) {
        self.addingMode = addingMode
    }
    
}
```

***Solution-:***

You can move `addingMode` and `sheetViewModel` property outside of `sheetView`, and put them inside  `PlaylistCreationView` just above **body** property. This way when sheet is refreshed your object wouldn’t be instantiated from scratch every time.

**Working Code-:**

```
mport SwiftUI

struct PlaylistCreationView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PlaylistCreationViewModel
    var sheetViewModel: SearchViewModel
    
    init(viewModel:PlaylistCreationViewModel) {
        _viewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
         sheetViewModel = SearchViewModel(addingMode: .playlist(onAddSong: {  addSong in
            viewModel.songs.append(addSong)
        }))
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.songs, id: \.self) { song in
                    Text(song)
                }
                Button("Add Song") {
                    viewModel.sheetType = .search
                }
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Playlist")
        }
        .sheet(item: $viewModel.sheetType) { _ in
            sheetView
        }
    }
    
    private var sheetView: some View {
         NavigationView {
            SearchView(model: sheetViewModel)
                .navigationTitle("Search")
        }
    }
    
}
```

**SearchView-:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SearchViewModel
    
    init(model:SearchViewModel) {
        _viewModel = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: model)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search", text: $viewModel.search)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            List(viewModel.songs, id: \.self) { song in
                Button(song) {
                    switch viewModel.addingMode {
                    case .playlist(onAddSong: let onAddSong):
                        onAddSong(song)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Yes it works. I had to add the `onDismiss` parameter on the `.sheet()` to instantiate a new `SearchViewModel` each time the `SearchView` is dismissed. I don't expected a view model property change to reload all the view body. Thanks again